# Why do we subtract least count in measurement? Trying to understand intuitively

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics

With respect to the following situation, it is quite clear that our true reading has to be at least 21degC. It can be more than that such as 21.4, 21.5. 21.7 etc. We can also see that the maximum value can be 22 ( or very very close to 22). 
But I am unable to understand how it can be less than 21degC.  As per the figure, it says the minimum value is 21-0.5= 20.5degC.   And the maximum value is 21.5degC.  How this correct? I am trying to understand this intuitively.
Kindly help me understand.

Image courtesy:  [Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ul3e-HXAeZA&list=LLJYFI_Q9cjE1XqJ_3VHZOkQ&index=3&t=0s)

[image]

Comment: I would call it 21.4 deg C, and if I had to put a plus/minus on it, I would say +/- 0.2.  This is admittedly a judgment call, but it is obvious that the temperature noted in the figure is not the best way to report the measured value.

Comment: @David White OKK. But then what will be the better way of reporting measured value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Please be more specific.

Comment: @DavidWhite I am referring to this statement   "but it is obvious that the temperature noted in the figure is not the best way to report the measured value".

Comment: Related [How to interpolate when reading a scale.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/496562/104696)  I would quote the reading to be $21.5\pm 0.5\,^\circ \rm C$.

Comment: @gpuguy, you can tell by looking at the thermometer that the reading cannot be as low as 20.5 deg C.  You also know that you can read the thermometer with more precision than 0.5 deg C.

Comment: @DavidWhite exactly, so why does the author takes it that wrong way:  21+-0.5?

Comment: @Farcher. Ok but why authors in books and also in this video take it 21+-0.5?

Comment: @gpuguy, authors make mistakes too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are multiple approaches to quoting accuracy.

The conventional “quote 1 sigma” form is not the only one.

In this case, they are apparently writing $x \pm y$ to say “we expect that the true value is somewhere within $y$ of $x$, and never outride that range”. That’s common in school because it’s easy to explain. But I’ve never seen it actually used in professional science and engineering. It’s more related to a “quote significant figures” approach than to a real error analysis.

That said, in school and in life you should figure out what conventions are being used to communicate, and stick with them. Picking your own conventions can [cause problems in conversion.](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/weekly/6Page53.pdf).

Comment: Great!. Could you please elaborate your answer especially quote significant figure approach.